AWS unable to create EBS snapshot. Lifecyle Manager error --> fail to fetch
I cannot create snapshots of my EBS volume. In the the volumes' menu I have a window that says:
Fault Tolerance for all volumes in this region -->Data Lifecycle Manager default policy for EBS Snapshots status:Failed to fetch default policy status
So I went to Lifecycle Manager and I only get a message that says: fail to fetch
Does anyone know what's wrong?
Thanks

Today, I am trying to use this feature, and the same message appeared.
I followed the wizard to create a new policy and at the last step it said "Fail to fetch".
It seems like it worked during all wizard steps, but the creation attempt error happened.
After that also calling from the menu directly the same message appears.
At this moment I still think it is on AWS side. But some sources mentioned permissions which is not expected since on AWS permission messages are different.
Anyhow, not a clear message from the user perspective.
